# Displaying Data on a Pie chart in ChartsJs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I was able to create this doughnut chart that displays data. However, now that I look at it, I would like add the number value of the foods (100,200,300) below, on a second line, instead of having next to the food item itself.  Is there a way to do this? I was thinking that since this is a nested array, looping through it may work?  Any thoughts?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
   label1: [["Pizza: 100"], ["Hot Dogs: 200"], ["Burgers:300"]],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
       
        title: function(tooltipItem, data, label1, label2) {
          return data ['label1'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
        },
        afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data['datasets'][0];
          var percent = Math.round((dataset['data'][tooltipItem['index']] / dataset["_meta"][0]['total']) * 100)
          return '(' + percent + '%)';
        }
      },
      backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      titleFontSize: 16,
      titleFontColor: '#0066ff',
      bodyFontColor: '#000',
      bodyFontSize: 14,
      displayColors: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
    <div id="chartjs-tooltip">
       <table></table>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: `label1: [["Pizza: 100"], ["Hot Dogs: 200"], ["Burgers:300"]]` is just `label`,the data calculated is `data: [12, 19, 3]`. `label` will show when you hover it,the `percentage` is calculated by `data: [12, 19, 3]`.I am confused of what you want to do.

Comment: Like LiuYu said ==> Very hard to understand your issue.  Add a screenshot of the result you want. Maybe this is related: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/